# Using Flume to Ingest data from kafka to HDFS:: ConfigurationException: Bootstrap Servers must be specified

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

I am trying to ingest data using flume from kafka source to hdfs. Below is my flume conf file.

```
flume1.sources = kafka-source-1
flume1.channels = hdfs-channel-1
flume1.sinks = hdfs-sink-1
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.bootstrap.servers = localhost:9092
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.zookeeperConnect = localhost:2181
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.topic = MYNEWSFEEDS
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.batchSize = 100
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.channels = hdfs-channel-1
flume1.channels.hdfs-channel-1.type   = memory
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.channel = hdfs-channel-1
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.type = hdfs
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.filePrefix = test-events
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.path = hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.rollCount=100
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.rollSize=0
flume1.channels.hdfs-channel-1.capacity = 10000
flume1.channels.hdfs-channel-1.transactionCapacity = 1000
```

I am using below command to run flume agent:

```
sudo flume-ng agent --name flume1 --conf-file '/etc/flume-ng/conf/flafka.conf' Dflume.root.logger=TRACE,console
```

But I am getting below error:

> 18/03/12 16:49:18 ERROR node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Source
>   kafka-source-1 has been removed due to an error during configuration
>   org.apache.flume.conf.ConfigurationException: Bootstrap Servers must
>   be specified  at
>   org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource.doConfigure(KafkaSource.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.source.BasicSourceSemantics.configure(BasicSourceSemantics.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.source.AbstractPollableSource.configure(AbstractPollableSource.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:326)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Although, I have specified the Bootstrap Servers in conf file but still it give same error. Have tried many permutations and combinations but no success.

Comment: Any reason you're using Flume than Kafka Connect?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [official JavaDoc](https://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.7.0/apidocs/constant-values.html#org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSourceConstants.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS), you should replace

```
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.bootstrap.servers = localhost:9092
```

with

```
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.kafka.bootstrap.servers = localhost:9092
```